# How do I initialize a variable in the main method, and then use it to paint a graphic on screen AFTER it has been initialized

Tags: java, graphics

My problem is that I need to declare all the variables in my main method so that I can pass them to other classes in the future. The problem is that I can't call the paint method from my main method, so I have to declare all the variables inside my painting method. What I need is to declare the variables in a way that they are accessible to my main method, and then pass them to my drawing method. How can I do this it seems impossible and I've spent hours trying to figure it out I'm stuck. Code:

```
package main;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.* ;
import java.awt.* ;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

public class Rebellion extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;      
        doDrawing(g2d) ;
    }

 private void doDrawing(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    g2d.setPaint(Color.green);
    for (int i = 0 ; i < 601; i+= 50) {
        g2d.drawLine(0, i, 600, i) ;
        g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, 600) ;
    }  

    //randomizing the amount of planets
    int planetCount = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 9 ;
    Planets [] worlds = new Planets[planetCount] ;
    worldGenerator(planetCount, worlds) ;

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 1 ; i < planetCount ; i++) {
        int xCords = worlds[i].getX() ;
        int yCords = worlds[i].getY() ;
        g2d.fillOval(xCords,yCords,15,15) ;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    //creating primary window
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Rebellion Simulator 2735");
    Rebellion game = new Rebellion();
    frame.add(game) ;
    frame.setSize(800, 632);
    frame.setResizable(false); //new
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); //new
    frame.setLayout(null) ; //new


    //Buttons
    JButton test = new JButton("Ship #");
    test.setBounds(650, 200, 100, 30);
    frame.add(test);

    test.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StrategyScreen StrategyScreen = new StrategyScreen() ;
            StrategyScreen.setVisible(true) ;
        }
    });

    //max size of board (600,600)
    final int xMax = 600 ; 
    final int yMax = 600 ;     

 }
}
```

to sum it up: I need the main method to initialize the variables planetCount, Planets [] array, and run the worldGenerator() method (didn't include in the code it's not important). After they are initialized in the main method they then have to be passed to paint to be painted... Thanks!

Comment: You could use instance fields or some kind of shared model

Comment: Hi Adam, the main method is a static method and it has access to all static members declared at the class level, but your paint method i.e. the paintComponent() method is a non-static or instance method, which can only be called from an object of Rebellion type. So I would say don't declare your variables in the main method. Declare them at the class level without the static qualifier. So all of those variables would be instance variables. Next step is to write all your variable initialization code in a constructor Rebellion(){} and then in the main method just create an object of type class

Answer (score 0):

the main method is a static method and it has access to all static members declared at the class level, but your paint method i.e. the paintComponent() method is a non-static or instance method, which can only be called from an object of Rebellion type. So I would say don't declare your variables in the main method. Declare them at the class level without the static qualifier. So all of those variables would be instance variables. Next step is to write all your variable initialization code in a constructor Rebellion(){} and then in the main method just create an object of type class. Though the code below will not run as it is, try to use it as a template to make sense of what was mentioned above.  I have commented the code to stress on the changes to be done to solve your problem.

```
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

public class Rebellion extends JPanel {
//Declare your variable as instance variables without static keyword
private JFrame frame;
private Rebellion game;
private JButton test;
private StrategyScreen StrategyScreen;

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.getTest(); //Just an example. Here you are accessing your JButton object which you can modify in your paint method
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    doDrawing(g2d);
}

//All getters and setters of your Rebellion instance variables declared here

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public void setFrame(JFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}

public Rebellion getGame() {
    return game;
}

public void setGame(Rebellion game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public JButton getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(JButton test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public StrategyScreen getStrategyScreen() {
    return StrategyScreen;
}

public void setStrategyScreen(StrategyScreen strategyScreen) {
    StrategyScreen = strategyScreen;
}

private void doDrawing(Graphics2D g2d) {
    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g2d.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 600);

    g2d.setPaint(Color.green);
    for (int i = 0; i < 601; i += 50) {
        g2d.drawLine(0, i, 600, i);
        g2d.drawLine(i, 0, i, 600);
    }

    // randomizing the amount of planets
    int planetCount = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 9;
    Planets[] worlds = new Planets[planetCount];
    worldGenerator(planetCount, worlds);

    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    for (int i = 1; i < planetCount; i++) {
        int xCords = worlds[i].getX();
        int yCords = worlds[i].getY();
        g2d.fillOval(xCords, yCords, 15, 15);
    }

}

public Rebellion() { //Code now moved to Constructor instead of the main method
    // creating primary window
    frame = new JFrame("Rebellion Simulator 2735");
    game = new Rebellion();
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setSize(800, 632);
    frame.setResizable(false); // new
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null); // new
    frame.setLayout(null); // new

    // Buttons
    test = new JButton("Ship #");
    test.setBounds(650, 200, 100, 30);
    frame.add(test);

    test.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            StrategyScreen = new StrategyScreen();
            StrategyScreen.setVisible(true);
        }
    });

    // max size of board (600,600)
    final int xMax = 600;
    final int yMax = 600;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rebellion reb = new Rebellion(); //You just create an instance of the class which invokes the constructor and gets all your initialization done
    reb.paintComponent(g); // Pass your Graphics object here
}
}
```

Comment: thank you. I made the changes and it works but one problem, I can't create my own graphics variable G, so in the main method how would I call: reb.paintComponent(g) ?

Comment: Hi Adam, you dont have to create your Graphics object, just have your main method have these lines

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Rebellion reb = new Rebellion(); //You just create an instance of the class which invokes the constructor and gets all your initialization done
    reb.doDrawing((Graphics2D)reb.getGraphics());
}